# UDPによるデータ送信のパケットロスを減らす方法について

Tags: c++, boost, network

いま、1つのアプリケーションで描画した画像を、もう1つのアプリケーションにリアルタイムで送信し、表示するようなプログラムを作成しています。ネットワークに関しては初心者なのですが、調べた限りでは、実際の映像ストリーミングではUDPが使われているということで、同じくUDPを使った通信を実装しました。
　具体的には、200 x 200の画像データを適当なアルゴリズムで圧縮し、約15000バイトほどのデータにしたあと、それを1398バイトの部分データに区切って、2バイトのデータのインデックス情報を付加した計1400バイトのデータをパケットに載せて送信します。送受信にはboostのasioライブラリを使用しました。送信側、受信側のともに、それ用のスレッドを用意し、それぞれひたすら送信・受信を行うようにしました。疑似的なコードで表すと以下のような感じです。

```
//送信側のコード
while(!stop_sending)
{
    //データの取得
    data = get_image();
    //データを分割して送信
    for(int idx = 0; idx < max; ++idx)
    {
        s_buf[idx] = segment(data, idx);
        udp_sock_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(s_buf[idx]), endpoint);
        //一応のスリープ（これは必要？）
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
    //送信間隔は30ms
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
}
```

---

```
//受信側
while(!stop_receiving)
{
    //データの受信
    auto len = sock_udp.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf_udp), sender_ep, 0, error);
    //取得したデータから画像を復元
    ...
}
```

以上の方法で、一応の画像の送受信は成功したのですが、送信の間隔を狭めるほど受信側でのパケットロスがひどくなり、リアルタイムな画像送受信が上手くいっていないような状況です。具体的には…

```
送信先 : 127.0.0.1  送受信のポート : 58900
 - 送信間隔 100 ms [推定送信速度 150kB/s] → パケットロスト率 約0~10%
 - 送信間隔 30 ms [推定送信速度 450kB/s] → パケットロスト率 約40~70%
```

のように、多くのパケットが受信時に失われており、画像が半分以上再現されないような状況です。ただ、送信開始から10フレームほどは（遅延はあるものの）完全に受信できており、その後突然としてパケットが失われ始めます。その原因も分かりかねています。450kB/sという伝送速度は、ローカルホストや同一LAN内の通信なら実現できると考えていたのですが、このパケットロスト率は仕方ないものなのでしょうか。改善できる方法などがあればご助言いただきたいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

送信間隔100msでゆっくりと送信して450kB/sで送信しているつもりかもしれませんが、実態としては1500kB/sで送信した後に33msのディレイを入れているに過ぎません。1500kB/sで送信したときに受信側のドライバの処理が追いつかなければ、容易にパケットをロストしてしまうでしょう。

1msのディレイを4msに変更して、33msのディレイを無くせば随分と安定するはずです。

Comment: プログラムの問題であるのは確かなのですが、理由の説明が間違っています。この程度のデータ量でドライバやネットワークスタックによる取りこぼしはあり得ません。[こちらの回答](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/24274/5793)の通り、アプリケーションがデータを読み込んでいないためにバッファがあふれている可能性が高いです。

Answer (score 6):

UDPの場合、フロー制御はアプリケーション側で行う必要があります。

> //取得したデータから画像を復元

復元処理に1ms以上要していれば当然バッファが溢れますが、その点はどうでしょうか？